# Asp.Net Core v1.1 Get Inherited Class Names From another project in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, asp.net-core

I m working with different inherited classes i want get this class names inherited from same interface

```
public class CollectorA : ICollector
{
    public string CollectSomething()
    {
        //DO Something
    }
}
public class CollectorB : ICollector
{
    public string CollectSomething()
    {
        //DO Something
    }
}
```

I want to do like :

```
public void Init(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{

    var types  = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                          .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                          .Where(type => type.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(ICollector)));
```

Getting types returns null I tried AppContext but still not works.

```
foreach(var item in types)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector,item.Name>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no [AppDomain](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/) in .NET Core so this
>   `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` is not there as well(None of
>   .NET Standard 1.x has it.) Here's the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919) detailing
>   this.

If you would like to go with the approach of PolyFill (AppDomain) in the [blog](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/),here's the code

```
public class AppDomain
 {
    public static AppDomain CurrentDomain { get; private set; }

    static AppDomain()
    {
        CurrentDomain = new AppDomain();
    }

    public Assembly[] GetAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
        foreach (var library in dependencies)
        {
            if (IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(library))
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
                assemblies.Add(assembly);
            }
        }
        return assemblies.ToArray();
    }

    private static bool IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(RuntimeLibrary compilationLibrary)
    {
        return compilationLibrary.Name == ("Specify")
            || compilationLibrary.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith("Specify"));
    }
}
```

And then You can use like this

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(ass => ass.ExportedTypes)
                          .Where(type => type.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(ICollector)));
            foreach (var item in types)
            {
                services.AddTransient(typeof(ICollector), item);
            }
```

For an alternate approach, Please refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007264/get-available-types-in-coreclr) to get an alternative for **GetAssemblies() or Types** .

Answer (score 2):

You can also add it like this

```
foreach(var item in types)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(ICollector), item);
}
```

Also in looking for the types try the following.

```
//get collectors
var types = typeof(CollectorA).Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(ICollector).IsAssignableFrom(t));

//add to service
foreach(var item in types)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(ICollector), item);
}
```

Comment: types value is null :)

Comment: @Batuhan, Ok hold on let me take a look at that. What type of project is this.

Comment: Class Library (ASP.NET-Core)- i m doing this processes from Console App.

Comment: Assembly does not contain definition for GetAssembly. Which Lib. must be added ?